# Gitlab - HTTPS authentication failed

Tags: https, gitlab

I am upgrading an old Gitlab (manually installed) from 5.0 to 8.0 through 5.1, 6.0, 6.1, 7.14 and 8.0.
Every steps were ok except the access through HTTPS with git command lines, in all versions.

A git clone over SSH iw working.
A git clone over HTTPS returns `fatal: Authentication failed for`.

If I modify a project by placing it as public, git clone over HTTPS works.

Web interface is working fine and I can log in to without issue.

What I am missing in the configuration ?

The SSL certificate used is a Let's Encrypt certificate.

Comment: You have got users and passwords on your system I assume?

Comment: sure I have ...

Comment: So, you're doing a command line pull, what option are you using?

Comment: I am doing a `git clone https://git.domain.com/toto.git`, the system asks me a login and a password. After that, I get le message `fatal: Authentication failed for ....` but my access are the good ones.

Comment: I found that in my original installation of gitlab (4.2), I configured it to use LDAP authentication. Now, my LDAP is gone, I disable LDAP authentication too. HTTPS is working.
On my test copy of Gitlab (upgraded in 5.0 etc), HTTPS authentication is working anymore. I found that my Gitlab account is still stagged as LDAP account, even if LDAP is disabled. If I create manually a new account, HTTPS authentication is working. So, is there a solution to "migrate" all previously created from LDAP accounts to a normal manually created gitlab account ?

Comment: Hmm, this may be of assistance.. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/1126

Comment: I'm assuming that in your `gitlab.rb` | `gitlab.yml` you have `gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = false` ?

Comment: This also looks like it may be an issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/19787

Comment: I have exactly the same issue than in your last link.Unfortunately, this topic doesn't give any solution.

Comment: Yeah, I see it's a bug, you may want to see if there's a better one open, or add your symptoms to the bug report..